# jquery circle progress | Change color on circle progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery-circle-progress plugin to draw a circle. As the circle increases (or decreases) in size, I want the color of the circle change smoothly accordingly.

I wrote a function with 100 different gradients, from green to orange to red. To make it more clear: the circle should always be 1 color, but the gradient of that color has to change seamless when the circle moves.

Here is a snip from what I already have:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxqBVq

As you can see, the color of the circle changes instantly to red when the circle size changes. How can I make the color change more smoothly?

HTML:

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Initialize circle with some default settings:

```js
var circle = $('.circle').circleProgress({
   value: 0.50,
   fill: { color: 'rgb(127,127,0)' }
});
```

The custom JavaScript function for the gradients:

```js
function setGradient(value) {
    // Start with: "if (value == 0.01)"
    if (value == 0.50) {
        color = 'rgb(127,127,0)';
    }
    if (value == 0.51) {
        color = 'rgb(132,122,0)';
    }
    if (value == 0.52) {
        color = 'rgb(137,117,0)';
    }
    if (value == 0.53) {
        color = 'rgb(142,112,0)';
    }
    if (value == 0.54) {
        color = 'rgb(147,107,0)';
    }
    if (value == 0.55) {
        color = 'rgb(153,102,0)';
    }
    if (value == 0.56) {
        color = 'rgb(158,96,0)';
    }
    if (value == 0.57) {
        color = 'rgb(163,91,0)';
    }
    if (value == 0.58) {
        color = 'rgb(168,86,0)';
    }
    if (value == 0.59) {
        color = 'rgb(173,81,0)';
    }
    if (value == 0.60) {
        color = 'rgb(178,76,0)';
    }
    // ... etc until: "if (value == 1.00)"
    return color;
}
```

The circle change after a few seconds:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    circle.circleProgress('value', 0.60);

    circle.one('circle-animation-progress', function() {
        $(this).circleProgress({
            fill: { color: setGradient(circle.circleProgress('value')) },
        })
    });
},3000);
```

Comment: Instead of thousands of ifs, you can calculate r, g and b based on the value, then put them together, like `color = \`rgb(${Math.round(r)}, ${Math.round(g)}, ${Math.round(b)})\``

Comment: @Chris G Yes, I was already looking into something like this. Just wanted to keep the example snippet very simple.

Comment: @elton73 do you have specific colours matching with values or an idea of the order of your gradient colour ?

Comment: @Laura Yes, it's defined in my setGradient() function. E.g.: when the value of the circle is 0.52, circle color will become rgb(137,117,0). I'm just trying to make a smooth color transition when the circle progresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://codepen.io/LauraBelavoir/pen/KeZLoY?editors=1010) an live example of the effect you want.

You can notice that two things have changed.

First, the `circle-animation-progress` change the `instance.arcFill` and doesn't fire `circleProgress` again. To obtain the new colour I pass the `stepValue` and not `value`.

```
var circle = $(".circle")
  .circleProgress({
    value: 0.5,
    fill: "rgb(127,127,0)"
  })
  .on("circle-animation-progress", 
    function(event, animationProgress, stepValue) {
      var instance = $(this).data("circle-progress");
      instance.arcFill = setGradient(stepValue);
  });

setTimeout(function() {
  circle.circleProgress("value", 0.6);
}, 3000);
```

Second, the `setGradient` is slightly different. As `stepValue` is a big decimal number, you've to compare as inferior (or superior) as a specific value and not equal like the following example:

```
function setGradient(value) {
  // Start with: "if (value == 0.01)"
  let color = "rgb(127,127,0)";
  if (value >= 0.5) {
    color = "rgb(127,127,0)";
  }
  if (value >= 0.51) {
    color = "rgb(132,122,0)";
  }
  if (value >= 0.52) {
    color = "rgb(137,117,0)";
  }
  if (value >= 0.53) {
    color = "rgb(142,112,0)";
  }
  if (value >= 0.54) {
    color = "rgb(147,107,0)";
  }
  if (value >= 0.55) {
    color = "rgb(153,102,0)";
  }
  if (value >= 0.56) {
    color = "rgb(158,96,0)";
  }
  if (value >= 0.57) {
    color = "rgb(163,91,0)";
  }
  if (value >= 0.58) {
    color = "rgb(168,86,0)";
  }
  if (value >= 0.59) {
    color = "rgb(173,81,0)";
  }
  if (value >= 0.6) {
    color = "rgb(178,76,0)";
  }
  // ... etc until: "if (value == 1.00)"
  return color;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. Well earned bounty!